# Python - replace vs update file

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have playlists being uploaded into a directory, based on their size.

first I upload the following `dict` to an empty directory:

```
playlist_pre = {'user1': {u'Codex': 1.0, u'High And Dry': 1.0, u'Hey': 1.0, u'O': 1.0, u'Videotape': 1.0, u'Pyramid Song': 1.0}}
```

then, this one:

```
playlist_pos = {'user1': {u'With Or Without You - Jo Whiley Show - BBC Live Session': 1.0, u'Codex': 1.0, u'Daydreaming': 1.0, u'The Man Who Sold The World - 2015 Remastered Version': 1.0, u'High And Dry': 1.0, u'Hey': 1.0, u'O': 1.0, u'Sparks': 1.0, u'Videotape': 1.0, u'Asleep - 2011 Remastered Version': 1.0, u'Pyramid Song': 1.0, u'Nude': 1.0}}
```

this is how I upload playlists to directory, again and again:

```
if os.path.exists('db/user1.json'):
        if len(playlist_pos['user1'].values()) < 3:
            with open('db/user1.json', 'r+') as f:
                db = playlist_pos
                db = json.load(f)
                # increment track count
                updateTrackCounts(db,value=1.0)
                #update json here
                f.seek(0)
                f.truncate()
                json.dump(db, f)
                print (db)
        else:
            with open('db/user1.json', 'r+') as f:
                db = playlist_pos
                db = json.load(f)
                # increment track count
                updateTrackCounts(db,value=1.0)
                #update json here
                f.seek(0)
                f.truncate()
                json.dump(db, f)
                print (db)
```

this is how I upload the first, `playlist_pre`, to an empty directory.

```
else:
    if len(playlist_pre['user1'].values()) < 3:
        with open('db/user1.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(playlist_pre, f)
    else:
        with open('db/user1.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(playlist_pre, f)
```

**ps: `function` being called:**

```
def updateTrackCounts(d, value=0):   
    for i in d:
        if isinstance(d[i], dict):
            updateTrackCounts(d[i], value)
        elif isinstance(d[i], float):
            d[i] += value
```

**EDIT**

this is desired output when `playlist_pre` is generated after `playlist_pos`: a new file joining pre and post playlists;

repeated tracks have an `incremented value`, and new tracks have `default value = 1.0`

```
 joined_playlist = {'user1': 
 {u'Codex': 2.0, u'High And Dry': 2.0, u'Hey': 2.0, u'O': 2.0, u'Videotape': 2.0, u'Pyramid Song': 2.0, u'With Or Without You - Jo Whiley Show - BBC Live Session': 1.0, u'Daydreaming': 1.0, u'The Man Who Sold The World - 2015 Remastered Version': 1.0, u'O': 1.0, u'Sparks': 1.0, u'Asleep - 2011 Remastered Version': 1.0, u'Nude': 1.0}}
```

Comment: It seems to me that you are always loading `db = json.load(f)` and that always points to `user1.json`.

Comment: how do I fix this?

Comment: The statements `db = playlist2` and `db = playslist1` are followed by the same `db = json.load(f)`: why are you overwriting the variable?

Comment: mistake. care to fix the code and answer?

Comment: I provided the answer. I also noticed a variable `playlist_short` not referenced before, so I assumed it to be same as `playlist1` for this sample.

Comment: I sort-of get what you are trying to do, but you need to formalize it better. Can you rename `playlist1` and `playlist2` to more meaningful names? Why do you call them `two different types` when they look just the same, with only more or less elements? What's the relationship between `p1` and `p2`? Or ultimately, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @sal please, refer to edit. I've renamed playlists, and tried to make myself  clear that I intend to **consolidate** playlists as they keep being uploaded. every time a new `key` is updated to `dict`, it gets default `'key': 1.0`. IF the new playlist has a repeated `key`, then, **an only then**, its `value` is incremented. basically, the function should be keeping track of all the times the track is being added to the consolidated playlist. did I make myself clear? thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the `db` variable gets overwritten by mistake, and thus always loads data from `db/user1.json`. The *quick* fix would be to comment out the `db = json.load(f)` statement in both branches: after all, you want to fully rewrite the file content.

I would though also implement the two code blocks as functions, as they repeat the same exact logic, and this makes it more readable and easier to debug:

```
import os
import json

playlist1 = {'user1': {u'Codex': 1.0, u'High And Dry': 1.0, u'Hey': 1.0, u'O': 1.0, u'Videotape': 1.0, u'Pyramid Song': 1.0}}
playlist2 = {'user1': {u'With Or Without You - Jo Whiley Show - BBC Live Session': 1.0, u'Codex': 1.0, u'Daydreaming': 1.0, u'The Man Who Sold The World - 2015 Remastered Version': 1.0, u'High And Dry': 1.0, u'Hey': 1.0, u'O': 1.0, u'Sparks': 1.0, u'Videotape': 1.0, u'Asleep - 2011 Remastered Version': 1.0, u'Pyramid Song': 1.0, u'Nude': 1.0}}


def updateTrackCounts(d, value=0):
    for i in d:
        if isinstance(d[i], dict):
            updateTrackCounts(d[i], value)
        elif isinstance(d[i], float):
            d[i] += value


def update_and_save_playlist(playlist, filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r+') as f:
        db = playlist
        # increment track count
        updateTrackCounts(db, value=1.0)
        # update json here
        f.seek(0)
        f.truncate()
        json.dump(db, f)
        print (db)


def save_playlist(playlist, filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(playlist, f)


if os.path.exists('db/user1.json'):
    if len(playlist1['user1'].values()) < 3:
        # save playlist 2
        update_and_save_playlist(playlist2, 'db/user1.json')
    else:
        # save playlist 1
        update_and_save_playlist(playlist1, 'db/user1.json')
else:
    if len(playlist1['user1'].values()) < 3:
        save_playlist(playlist2, 'db/user1.json')
    else:
        save_playlist(playlist1, 'db/user1.json')
```

**EDIT**
Looks more like a problem with *merging* the two playlists, pre/pos. For that the `updateTrackCounts` needs adjustments. Since the `new` playlist will contain more data than the `old`, one way would be to feed `updateTrackCounts` both playlists, and have it update *in-place* the new one, based on the tracks present in the old one:

```
def updateTrackCounts(new_dict, old_dict, value=0):
    # new_dict will have the same or more data than old_dict
    for user, new_tracks in new_dict.items():
        # check if this user, and the tracks were in the old dict
        if user in old_dict:
            for old_track in old_dict[user]:
                if old_track in new_tracks:
                    new_dict[user][old_track] += value
```

For example on usage, after calling:

```
updateTrackCounts(playlist_pos, playlist_pre, value=1.0)
```

`playlist_pos` will be same as `joined_playlist`

This might need adjustments based on your target: for example, this doesn't take into account the case when the old and new are the same as no change has happened.

Comment: I get new playlist with incremented value alright, but incremented values makes sense only to tracks present before. I posted an edit to clarify the desired output: new tracks with default value = 1.0 and repeated tracks with incremented value. can you still help please?